# How do I convert binary to decimal?

Tags: c

I coded today quickly (with help of looking up various google searches) for a basic assignment to convert binary to decimal. This is just the part that converts signed to 2's complement.

```
void binary_to_decimal (char *value){
    int i;
    int numdigits = strlen(value);
    int c=0;
    char nvalue[numdigits];
    char sum[numdigits];
    char b[numdigits];

    for(i=0;i<numdigits;i++)    
        b[i]='0';

    b[numdigits-1]='1';

    if (numdigits%4==0 && value[0]=='1')    {
        for(i=0;i<numdigits;i++){
            if(value[i]=='1')
                 nvalue[i]='0';
            else if(value[i]=='0')
                nvalue[i]='1';
    }

    for(i=0;i<numdigits;i++)
        printf("%c", nvalue[i]);

    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<numdigits;i++)
        printf("%c", b[i]);

    printf("\n");

    for(i=numdigits-1; i>=0; i--){
        nvalue[i]=nvalue[i]-'0';
        b[i]=b[i]-'0';
        sum[i]=(nvalue[i]^b[i]^c)+'0';
        c=(nvalue[i]&b[i]) | (b[i]&c) | (nvalue[i]&c);
    }

    if (c!=0)
        sum[0]=1;

    for(i=0;i<numdigits;i++)
        printf("%c", sum[i]);
    }
    else {

    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Obviously I could clean it up but thats not what i'm worried about.
This seems to work but I feel its different getting something to work and understanding every detail of getting it to work.

I would appreciate any feedback on the issue. Are things going to catch up with me?

I'm going to go back over the code for once and try to understand it, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean the difference between getting it to work and understanding every detail of how it works. You can get lucky hacking something together. BTW, you should not google too often if you're worried about understanding. Figure it out as much as you can on your own and don't worry about "quick"ness.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific and point out the exact line(s) you don't understand. BTW: Maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a good place to try

Comment: You can write tests to test your functions. I use the check framework to test my C https://libcheck.github.io/check/

Comment: Can you explain what the code does step by step in plain English? That's a reasonable test of whether you understand it.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yea, I wasn't sure if this is the right medium for this type of question but you basically said what I thought. I shouldn't hack it together, i should go through it piece by piece with the doc info and that way I actually know what I did. I'm not sure most people write code this way but I feel I would be hurting myself if I didn't approach it that way. Thanks.

Comment: @samgak Yea, I can understand each line, but I was concerned about overall ideas of why. I feel like its a part of programming that i've been neglecting, and it might be the most important part.

Comment: What is wrong with `long unsigned x = strtoul (value, NULL, 2);` ? (you have `errno` and the rest of the tests to validate conversion.)

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with the fact that this code do **not** `convert binary to decimal`. Maybe that was what you meant by:

> This is just the part that converts signed to 2's complement.

What this code (try to) do is to negate a value represented by a binary string. Like:

```
a = -a;
    ^
    Negate
```

The basic principal is:

1) Invert every bit in the original binary string

2) Add 1 to the result from the first step.

Example with 4 bit binary:

```
           0111 (is 7 )

1) Invert: 1000 (is -8)

2) Add 1:  1001 (is -7)
```

So your first loop does the invert and the second loop adds `1`.

However, you code is incorrect. If `numdigits%4==0 && value[0]=='1'` is false, you never initialize `nvalue` and your code has undefined behavior (in the second loop). I can't figure out why you use that `if` statement. It shouldn't be there. You should always execute the first loop.

Further - these lines seems strange:

```
}
else {

}
```

They don't match any opening statement.

In your code, you do all the calculations using `'0'` and `'1'` instead of just using `0` and `1`. Therefore you constantly have to convert between them, i.e.

```
`0` - `0` to convert to a real 0
`1` - `0` to convert to a real 1
```

and

```
0 + `0` to convert to a `0` (i.e. a printable 0)
1 + `0` to convert to a `1` (i.e. a printable 1)
```

that makes your code much more complicated than needed.

Instead you could keep things as real `0` and `1` - except when printing:

```
// This function negates a binary string by
//    a) Inverting each bit
//    b) Adding 1 to the inverted string
void negate_binary (char *value){
    int i;
    int numdigits = strlen(value);
    int c=0;
    char nvalue[numdigits];
    char sum[numdigits];
    char b[numdigits];

    // Set b to 1, i.e. 00000...0001
    for(i=0;i<numdigits;i++)    
        b[i]=0;
    b[numdigits-1]=1;

    // Invert all bits in the input string
    for(i=0;i<numdigits;i++){
        if(value[i]=='1')
             nvalue[i]=0;
         else if(value[i]=='0')
            nvalue[i]=1;
         else
             exit(1);  // Illegal input

    for(i=0;i<numdigits;i++)
        printf("%c", nvalue[i] + '0');

    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<numdigits;i++)
        printf("%c", b[i] + '0');

    printf("\n");

    // Do sum = nvalue + b (i.e. sum = nvalue + 1)
    for(i=numdigits-1; i>=0; i--){
        sum[i]=(nvalue[i]^b[i]^c);                     // Add with carry
        c=(nvalue[i]&b[i]) | (b[i]&c) | (nvalue[i]&c); // Calculate new carry
    }

    if (c!=0)
        sum[0]=1;

    for(i=0;i<numdigits;i++)
        printf("%c", sum[i] + '0');
    }
    else {

    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Yea, I did not include the part that proceeds to convert binary to decimal. I basically just worked out the part determining if it was a signed negative bit number, I was using this code (dealing with negative), which I had trouble working out for a bit. My goal in that code segment was to invert every bit and add 1. I have an else statement which basically treats it as unsigned for non negative numbers (Didn't include here). I don't think I used the correct medium to ask the difference between me writing it correctly and understanding it completely.

Comment: @C.B. That's what your doing (except for the bug I mentioned).

Comment: @C.B. - but which part is it that you don't understand? Is it the `invert` or is it the `add 1` ?

Comment: It's the add 1 . I think just talking about it made me feel better and narrowed it down to the part of the code where I need to evaluate the bit operations that are happening. (I initially assumed I didn't understand any of it). These statements:              nvalue[i]=nvalue[i]-'0';
            b[i]=b[i]-'0';
I wasn't sure about. I need to review this part more to understand the iterations that are occurring and why.

Comment: @C.B. - I tried to explain that part in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I just saw it. As far as not initializing the nvalue, would defining within the conditional if statement resolve this? I'll play with it tomorrow. I really appreciate the help. I need to look over this again. Thanks again.

Comment: @C.B.If you want to write code for **negating** a binary string (i.e. the code posted), you shall **not** have that if-statement at all. Just remove it as I did. If you want the if-statement because it is really part of a bigger code base, my answer is: I don't know - simply because I haven't see the bigger code base. :-)